# How to record and reuse database results for JUnit tests

Tags: java, database, testing, junit

I would like to leverage the existing database as a source for JUnit test data. Some scenarios are quite complex and it is a hassle to set up all the objects manually.

I am thinking in terms of a decorator for my existing DAO that will serialize the objects my real SQL connected DAO is returning from the database and record them to files.

Something along the lines of running the JUnit testcase in record once mode and afterwards always replaying the recorded data and not going to the database.

Are there frameworks for Java to ease this process or do I have to implement it myself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set up a logging JDBC proxy (like [JdbcProxy](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jdbcproxy/), [log4jdbc](http://code.google.com/p/log4jdbc/), [jdbcdslog](http://code.google.com/p/jdbcdslog) or [DbdaTestDriver](http://sourceforge.net/projects/dbdatestdriver/)) between your application and the database to save the queries and result sets returned. You won't have to write and inject any DAO decorators.

Later on you can use the logged data to set up a stub database connection for use in tests. JdbcProxy and DbdaTestDriver have built-in functions to do just that.

**[EDIT]** This project allows to record JDBC operations with later playback: http://sourceforge.net/projects/dbdatestdriver/

Comment: JdbcProxy looks like a good solution, too bad it seems to be abandoned.

Comment: found another one with replay functionality: http://sourceforge.net/projects/dbdatestdriver/

Answer (score 3):

Use a serialization framework (either the ugly built-in Java `Serialization` API or an XML or JSON mapper) to convert the beans into files and back. Many modern frameworks need only very few hints to do their work.

Options:

JSON: [Gson](https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) or [Jackson](http://www.cowtowncoder.com/hatchery/jackson/index.html)
XML: [Simple](http://simple.sourceforge.net/) or [Woodstox](http://woodstox.codehaus.org/)

That way, you don't have to go into JDBC at all. I always try to avoid to test the database - the vendor should do that. My tests only test whether I'm *using* the DB correctly. For that, I only need to check that query builders produce the correct SQL strings (but I don't need to send them to the database).

When testing the DB (sending data through the JDBC driver to the real thing), the test case should be as small and as simple as possible. I always run the tests against a specific test database which contains test cases and no production data. The difference is that each row of a test database has a purpose. A production database contains case A one million times, B one time and C is missing because it's so rare.

Saying "I want to test against a copy of the production database" is a polite way to say "I don't know what I'm doing, so I do a lot of it."

The test database is rebuilt from scratch when the first test runs (a static code block is your friend here). That prevents people from using it for anything. Each developer gets his/her own instance.

If you have a complex stored procedure, treat it like any other Java code: Test each path with the most simple test data.

All these rules have just two goal: Make everyone think twice before writing tests that hit a real database - and then decide against it. Second goal: If a test uses a database, it will succeed most of the time.

Answer (score 0):

Use a test database. Extract the data which you want to use for tests with [Jailer](http://jailer.sourceforge.net). Use [DBUnit](http://dbunit.sourceforge.net) for setting up the test database.

Comment: The DB calls are pretty vendor specific stored procs which makes a test db not really feasible.